# How to hide/display a page in a PDF based on a check box

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle-designer

I am creating an interactive PDF using Adobe Livecycle. My PDF has 4 pages and the last page is hidden.

I want to be able to display this hidden page based on a check box. Whenever a user selects this checkbox the page has to be visible.

I have used the action builder to change the presence of the last page to visible/hidden based on the checkbox. This was working fine until I added `baseProfile="interactiveForms"` to the template XML node in the XML Source. I had to add this tag in order to add custom javascript code to to the PDF. Without the `interactiveForms` attribute the action to hide/display the page works, but I am not able to add the custom javascript that I need to run on the PDF.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code on the exit event of the checkbox:

```
if (this.rawValue == 0){
   xfa.resolveNode("Page4").presence = "hidden";
}else{
   xfa.resolveNode("Page4").presence = "visible";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using this code previously but no luck. When I added the **baseProfile="interactiveForms"** tag to the XML source all the actions on the fields in the PDF stopped working. When I remove the tag everything works fine.